# "Begin to" or "Begin v.-ing"

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

It seems that "Begin/start to do something" is generally the correct form, as opposed to "Begin/start doing". Are there situations in which the latter is correct?

I've just come across this interesting sentence:

> "Begin reading this procedure, unless you have already begun to read it."

And indeed, to my foreign ears, the imperative "Begin to read" sounds less correct, or at least more awkward, than "Begin reading".

Comment: Your sentence is inherently paradoxical / nonsense (*by definition*, it's not possible for the reader to avoid being in the "unless" category, since he must have already read the 4 preceding words to get to that point in the text). But ***syntactically*** it would make no difference whatsoever if we reversed the two verb forms: *Begin **to read** this procedure, unless you have already begun **reading** it.* Or indeed both instances could be infinitives, or both could be continuous participles. What was the question again?

Comment: The sentence was of course meant to be that way. Anyway, yes, that was the question. So I understand that both forms are syntactically valid. But wouldn't you say that "begin to" is more common?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that "begin to" is more common, no. Note that it certainly doesn't help that the actual ***example usage*** on this page is extremely "weird". But we could look at some more "normal" utterances... [Unquestionably,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=began+to+feel%2Cbegan+feeling&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbegan%20to%20feel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbegan%20feeling%3B%2Cc0) *He began to feel scared* is far more common than *He began feeling scared.* But *He began painting landscapes some years later* sounds fine to me.

Comment: (And [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=began+painting+landscapes%2Cbegan+to+paint+landscapes&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) the NGram showing that there's not much difference in prevalence between ***began painting landscapes*** and ***began to paint landscapes***.)